# How to get the sales order date from the REST api?

Tags: api, rest-api

I am facing a very puzzling aspect of the REST API of Magento. Seemingly, the [GET /Orders](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html#RESTAPI-Resource-SalesOrders-HTTPMethod-GET-orders) response does not return any date. This can't be right, sales orders are dated.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. You should get the order date back. The field is called `created_at`.
In case you are not getting it, check if it is allowed in the Attributes section. `System->Web Services->REST Attributes` and click on the user type `Admin`.
If you didn't test, and just looked at the link you mentioned in the question then you should try it. I think that link just offers an example. It's not the real thing.

I just did a test and here is what came back:

```
Array
(
    [41] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 41
            [status] => pending
            [coupon_code] => 
            [shipping_description] => United Parcel Service - Ground
            [customer_id] => 
            [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_grand_total] => 823.4500
            [base_shipping_amount] => 11.5700
            [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal] => 750.0000
            [base_tax_amount] => 61.8800
            [base_total_paid] => 
            [base_total_refunded] => 
            [discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [grand_total] => 823.4500
            [shipping_amount] => 11.5700
            [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [store_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
            [subtotal] => 750.0000
            [tax_amount] => 61.8800
            [total_paid] => 
            [total_refunded] => 
            [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 811.8800
            [base_total_due] => 
            [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [subtotal_incl_tax] => 811.8800
            [total_due] => 
            [increment_id] => 100000049
            [base_currency_code] => USD
            [discount_description] => 
            [remote_ip] => 216.113.168.131
            [store_currency_code] => USD
            [store_name] => Main Website
Main Website Store
English
            [created_at] => 2013-03-15 02:01:34
            [shipping_incl_tax] => 11.5700
            [base_customer_balance_amount] => 0.0000
            [customer_balance_amount] => 0.0000
            [payment_method] => checkmo
            [gift_message_from] => 
            [gift_message_to] => 
            [gift_message_body] => 
            [tax_name] => US-CA-*-Rate 1
            [tax_rate] => 8.2500
            [addresses] => Array
                ( 
               .....
```

Notice the `created_at` field.
I tested with JSON format, but I don't think that makes a difference.